# Exists and forall in formal language definition in the case of kleene star

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

Let's suppose we have language $Y = \{a^ib^j:i,j \in N^*\}$ defined over the alphabet $\Sigma^{}_{} = \{a, b\}$

If we want to define this language $\Sigma^{*}_{}$ \ $\ Y$ such that we don't have the case of $a$ preceding all occurances of $b$, one way I found it defined is like this:
$ \Sigma^{*}_{}$ \ $\ Y = \{w_1baw_2 : w_1,w_2 \in \Sigma^{*}_{}\}$ but this doesn't include $aa$ for example, which should be there as well. Also, they assume intermediate following.

Thus, I made this solution:

$\Sigma^{*}_{}$ \ $Y = \{w \in \Sigma^{*}_{}: \exists i \in \{1,2, ...,|w| \}, w_i = b \implies \exists j \in \{i+ 1, i+2, ...,|w| \}, w_{j} = a\}$

The second language is $X = \{a, ba\}$, if we want t get $X^*$ which is for each $b$ to be  followed by $a$, I gave this solution: $X^* = \{w \in \Sigma^{*}_{}: \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3, ..., |w|\}, w_i = b \implies w_{i+1} = a\}$ Is this correct?

Comment: Please focus on one question only.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  We are a question-and-answer site, and we require you to articulate a specific question.  Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: I have given the feedback about "is this correct?" before: [1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154848/#comment325629_154848), [2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154870/#comment325674_154870).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let $Y = \{ a^i b^j \mid i,j>0\}$.You are looking for $\Sigma^* \setminus Y$, the complement of $Y$. As you state this consists of all strings having a $b$ before an $a$, or having only $a$ or only $b$'s. Your second solution ("if there exists a $b$ then there is an $a$ at a later position") does not seem to cover the case of only $a$'s.

I would use the regular expression $\Sigma^* \setminus Y = \Sigma^* ba \Sigma^* \cup a^* \cup b^*$. Indeed $\Sigma^* b\Sigma^*a \Sigma^*$ would cover the "$b$ before $a$" part of the language, but you can verify that then there must be a $b$ immediately followed by an $a$. (Start with any pair $b\dots a$, what is after the $b$? If that is an $a$ you are done, if that is another $b$, continue from there.)

In your second question $X^* = \{ a,ba\}^*$ is indeed the language where each $b$ is followed by an $a$. Related to your first language, that is the complement if the language where two $b$ are next to another, and also we cannot end with a $b$: $\Sigma^* \setminus (\Sigma^* bb \Sigma^* \cup \Sigma^* b)$.

Interestingly you use a logical notation for your languages. You use positions $i,j$, specify letters at these positions "w_i=a", I would use $a(i)$, and can compare the order of positions $i<j$. This is known as the first-order specification of languages. These form a strict subset of the regular languages, to be precise the [star-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-free_language) regular languages. To cover all regular languages you need monadic second order logic, which also allows one to use sets of positions and quantify over them. An example if a language that cannot be expressed in first-order is $(aa)^*$ the set of strings with an even number of $a$'s.

For $\Sigma^* \setminus Y $ we have
$ (\exists i)(\exists j) [\; b(i) \land a(j) \land i<j \;] \lor\lnot(\exists i)  b(i) \lor \lnot(\exists i) a(i)$

For $\{ a,ba\}^*$ one needs to specify "successor" $j=i+1$ in the logic. When this is not a given predicate one can define it using $<$ as follows: $i<j \land \lnot(\exists k)[i<k \land k<j]$.

Then we get $(\forall i)[\; b(i) \to (\exists j)(\;a(j) \land j=i+1\;) \;]$. Your syntax may vary.

Comment: For this regular expression: $\Sigma^* \setminus Y = \Sigma^* ba \Sigma^* \cup a^* \cup b^*$ Isn't abbabaab matching, how do you read that regular expression?

Comment: Agreed, that word is matching the complement, as it should. It is not of the form $a$'s then $b$'s. The expression given means: subword $ba$, or only $a$'s, or only $b$'s.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I replied when I just woke up, we need at least one instance of $ba$. Thank you very much for your reponse.

Comment: I can understand the logic of complement of languages with $\forall$, which is $\exists$ But for the the language where $a$ comes after $b$, which is as you stated $\Sigma^* \setminus \Sigma^* bb \Sigma^*$, but how would you specify it without the complement symbol. I did it with logical notation, and as you have pointed out, that won't include $aa$. This is not possible $X^* = \{w \in \Sigma^{*}_{}: \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3, ..., |w|-1\}, w_{i} = b \implies w_{i+1} = a\} \cup a^*$ ?

Comment: I didn't do $b^*$ because it's not possible there.

Comment: To be more precise, in my above question there seems to be to types of questions, one where where we move from $\forall$ to $\exists$, where is the first question, and it seems easy, for the second one, it seems, with your reformulating as a complement of another language, we have the case from $\exists$ to $\forall$l, that is, we are not looking for a word to have at least one case of $ba$, but for all $b$s there should be $a$ coming after. This is why I "had" to use the logical implication, otherwise, I don't know how to specify that. Thanks again.